# Microsoft Azure get access token API not working with cURL/Ruby but works with powershell

Tags: ruby, powershell, azure, curl, typhoeus

I am simply trying to get an access token from client id, client secret and tenant ID. Following powershell command works successfully

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri https://login.microsoftonline.com/TENANT/oauth2/token?api-version=1.0 -Method Post -Body @{"grant_type" = "client_credentials"; "resource" = "https://management.core.windows.net/"; "client_id" = "CLIENTID"; "client_secret" = "SECRET" }
```

But this curl doesn't work

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d "grant_type=client_credentials&resource=https://management.core.windows.net/&client_id=CLIENTID&client_secret=SECRET" "https://login.microsoftonline.com/TENANT/oauth2/token?api-version=1.0"
```

Neither this ruby script

```
require 'json'
require 'typhoeus'

url = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/TENANT/oauth2/token?api-version=1.0'
params = "grant_type=client_credentials&resource=https://management.core.windows.net/&client_id=CLIENTID&client_secret=SECRET"
HEADERS = {
"Content-Type" => "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
}
resp = Typhoeus::Request.post(url, body: params, headers: HEADERS)
```

I am following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-rest-api#calling-resource-manager-rest-apis) link. Any clues why neither of curl / ruby works ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the error message?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your issue successfully, and I discovered that the issue was caused by curl without OpenSSL and Typhoeus request without setting `ssl_verifypeer: false`.

So please follow [this](https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus#ssl) to check via `curl --version` and install openssl libraries on your environment.

Here is my sample code.

```
require "typhoeus"

url = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tanet-id>/oauth2/token?api-version=1.0'
params = "grant_type=client_credentials&resource=https://management.core.windows.net/&client_id=<client-id>&client_secret=<client-key>"
headers = {
    "Content-Type" => "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
}
request = Typhoeus.post(url, body: params, headers: headers, ssl_verifypeer: false)
puts request.code, request.body
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't help. Even with ssl_verifypeer: false option. It still recognizes my client_secret as invalid. I tried my openssl version and it shows 'OpenSSL/1.0.1f'. Any other error in my code ?
@Peter Pan

Comment: @Gagan93 Nothing. Without  `ssl_verifypeer: false` option, I got the result as same as yours.

Comment: Pan - You mean to say that by using this option, you also got the error (and not the generated token) ?